# Print only the names of dictionaries from within a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries, and I'm trying to iterate through the list to print the name of the dictionary and some info from each.

an example of what I've tried:

```
thingA = {'value1' : 1, 'value2' : 2} 
thingB = {'value1' : 1, 'value2' : 2}
mylist = [thingA, thingB] 

print("Things in mylist: ")
for thing in mylist:
    print(thing + " has values " + thing.get('value1') + " and " + thing.get('value2'))
```

desired output:

```
thingA has values 1 and 2
thingB has values 1 and 2
```

This particular example doesn't work because thing isn't a string, its a dictionary. Using str() to convert to string gets rid of the dictionary name altogether and just prints the contents. It seems like this should be really simple to do but I haven't been able to find any solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to print the contents of a list of dictionaries along with an index, I would probably do it with a simple fstring, like so:

```
thingA = {"value1": 1, "value2": 2}
thingB = {"value1": 1, "value2": 2}
mylist = [thingA, thingB]

print("Things in mylist: ")
for index, thing in enumerate(mylist):
    print(f"{index=} {thing=}")

Output:

Things in mylist: 
index=0 thing={'value1': 1, 'value2': 2}
index=1 thing={'value1': 1, 'value2': 2}
```

You could then add to the string if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

print("Things in mylist: ")

The following is written in pseudocode, not being familiar with the exact syntax of python, but rather to show you the logic.

If you want to print many values from thing:

Instead of writing
`thing.get('value1') + " and " + thing.get('value2') + "and" +  thing.get('value3') + " and " + thing.get('value4')` etc, you could just have a nested for loop:

```
for thing in mylist:
    print(thing + " has the values:")
    /**pseudocode
     for v = 0; v < thing's size; v++:
        value = thing.get(v)
        print(value + " and ") 

     */
```

The logic of this, if the pseudocode worked, is:

myList.get(0) is thing
prints *thing's name* "has the values:"
then it prints value1, value2, value3, etc, all the way up to the length-1 of the list.

So you might get:

Animal names has the values: (iteration 0 of for loop 0)
dog and (iteration 0 of for loop 1)
cat and (iteration 1 of for loop 1)
fish and (iteration 2 of for loop 1)
cow and (iteration 3 of for loop 1)
turtle and (iteration 4 of for loop 1)
sheep and (iteration 5 of for loop 1)

etc.
That's just the first iteration of the first for loop.

As for getting the name of the dictionary, I suggest researching the String methods in Python. There surely is a way out there to turn the name into a string. If not, you can try making an array of dictionary names - so names[0] might be the actual name of your first dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the example above isn't my actual code (can't share it for privacy reasons). Its just a super simplified example to ask about the problem I ran into with printing the dictionary name. Creating a separate list with just the dictionary names should work, but it seems pretty redundant vs just retrieving the name from the existing list.

Comment: String[]PinkColors={};
        String[]PurpleColors={};
        String[]RedColors={};
        String[]OrangeColors={};
        String[]YellowColors={};
        String[]GreenColors={;
        String[]CyanColors={};
        String[]BlueColors={};
        String[]BrownColors={};
        String[]WhiteColors={};
        String[]GreyColors={}; String[][]ColorArray = {PinkColors, PurpleColors, RedColors};
        String[]ColorArrayNames = {"Pink","Purple","Red"};

Comment: Above is an example of how creating a separate group of the names of groups (in the above case, ArrayLists; in your case, Lists/Dictionaries) can be used to reference a wide set of data. This tactic was never actually used, but in theory it would allow a user to enter "Pink", for example, if they want all the pink colors. "Pink" is then compared in a for loop against each String in ColorArrayNames, and when it is found at [0], [0] is noted, and [0] *in the String[][] is retrieved: allowing all the pink colors to be printed.

Comment: The other answers probably have better info for you, but this theory might help in another project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the items' names, you should use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
mylist = {"thingA": {'value1' : 1, 'value2' : 2},
          "thingB": {'value1' : 3, 'value2' : 4}}

print("Things in mylist: ")
for thing, values in mylist.items():
    print(f"{thing} has values {values['value1']} and {values['value2']}")
```

Output:

```
Things in mylist: 
thingA has values 1 and 2
thingB has values 3 and 4
```

If you don't require the names, you can iterate over the list with:

```
thingA = {'value1' : 1, 'value2' : 2} 
thingB = {'value1' : 3, 'value2' : 4}
mylist = [thingA, thingB] 

print("Things in mylist: ")
for index, thing in enumerate(mylist):
    print(f"thing{index} has values {thing['value1']} and {thing['value2']}")
```

Output:

```
Things in mylist: 
thing0 has values 1 and 2
thing1 has values 3 and 4
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work because I need to append an arbitrary number of dictionaries to the list, and you can't append to a dictionary. Is there anything that will work for both?

Comment: Why can't you append to a dictionary? `mylist["thingC"] = {'value1' : 5, 'value2' : 6}`

Comment: I'm currently using something like 

`mylist.append(thingFunction(thingC))`

to populate the list, where thingFunction returns the dictionary. I can probably figure out a way to convert it to use a dictionary but will need to re-write a bunch of existing code around that. Is there really no way to do this from a list?

Comment: Once you put a variable in a list (`mylist = [thingA, thingB] `) the name is lost. You can only access them by index. Are the names required?

Comment: I do require the names unfortunately. After some more research I think I can do a quick workaround using defaultdict instead of a list and/or adding a 'name' key in the dictionary and keep most of my existing code. Thanks for your help on this one!